# Elasticsearch boosting query

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm trying to use the boosting query in Elasticsearch (using the official elasticsearch gems in Rails) like this:

```
{
  "query"=>{
    "boosting"=>{
      "positive"=>[
        {
          "filtered"=>{
            "query"=>{
              "bool"=>{
                "should"=>[
                  {
                    "match"=>{
                      "_all"=>{
                        "query"=>"Filipstad",
                        "fuzziness"=>0.7
                      }
                    }
                  }
                ],
                "minimum_number_should_match"=>1
              },
              "filter"=>{
                "terms"=>{
                  "_type"=>[
                    "article",
                    "department"
                  ]
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      "negative"=>[
        {
          "filtered"=>{
            "filter"=>{
              "and"=>[
                {
                  "not"=>{
                    "term"=>{
                      "department_id"=>1
                    }
                  }
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      "negative_boost"=>0.1
    }
  }
}
```

When I run this I get the error `[boosting] query requires 'negative' query to be set'`. I can't figure out why! I have a negative query?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a syntax error in the above query the query part of  [filtered query](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-filtered-query.html) in the positive  is missing a parenthesis

This below should be syntactically correct ,

```
{
  "query"=>{
    "boosting"=>{
      "positive"=>[
        {
          "filtered"=>{
            "query"=>{
              "bool"=>{
                "should"=>[
                  {
                    "match"=>{
                      "_all"=>{
                        "query"=>"Filipstad",
                        "fuzziness"=>0.7
                      }
                    }
                  }
                ],
                "minimum_number_should_match"=>1
              }
            },
            "filter"=>{
              "terms"=>{
                "_type"=>[
                  "article",
                  "department"
                ]
              }
            }
            }
          }
      ],
      "negative"=>[
        {
          "filtered"=>{
            "filter"=>{
              "and"=>[
                {
                  "not"=>{
                    "term"=>{
                      "department_id"=>1
                    }
                  }
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      "negative_boost"=>0.1
    }
  }
}
```

however i should point out that the filtered query in the negative boost section can be  simplified further.

Comment: thank you! Regarding simplifying the negative boost section there will be some more filters added there. What did you have in mind?

Comment: oh i didn't take into account additional filters, however it is always better to use bool in filter instead of not/and whenever possible http://www.elasticsearch.org/blog/all-about-elasticsearch-filter-bitsets/